# Docker login: nvcr.io/v2 404

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run some Nvidia docker containers in WSL2 but I need to authenticate first, but `docker login` is giving me an error:

```
(base) ian@IansDesktop:~$ docker login ncvr.io
Username: $oauthtoken
Password:
INFO[0011] Error logging in to endpoint, trying next endpoint  error="login attempt to https://ncvr.io/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found"
login attempt to https://ncvr.io/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `$` in `$oauthtoken` on purpose? If yes, would `docker login -u "$oauthtoken" ncvr.io` work?

Comment: @ErikMD yes, I'm following the  instructions from https://ngc.nvidia.com/setup/api-key (login required) which states `For the username, enter '$oauthtoken' exactly as shown. It is a special authentication token for all users.`. I tried your command, same error. Weirdly though your command still prompted for a username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo. You've just sent your login credentials to `ncvr.io`. The registry for Nvidia is `nvcr.io`.

Comment: Thanks! I was making the same mistake