# WSL, CUDA and tensorflow setup without Nvidia driver

Tags: tensorflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

for the past 8 months or so I've been running tensorflow (2.4) in WSL 2. I'm now rebuilding this machine and I've noticed that Nvidia WSL CUDA drivers are no longer hosted by Nvidia:

```
We will no longer host any preview driver for WSL2 on developer zone. Developers on the Windows Insider Program may continue to receive bleeding edge driver with bug fixes and improvements through Windows Update.
```

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl

How else can I set up a tensorflow CUDA environment in WSL?

I have already tried using Nvidia docker containers but that failed, see this question for specifics:

[Docker login: nvcr.io/v2 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71628120/docker-login-nvcr-io-v2-404)

Comment: It this just a grammar issue? It says they will not host preview drivers, and before that clearly say that drivers are available: "The NVIDIA Windows GeForce or Quadro production (x86) driver that NVIDIA offers comes with CUDA and DirectML support for WSL and can be downloaded from below."

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy that's possible, but I think the fact I can't find the actual drivers anywhere for download removes the ambiguity for me. However, when posting this I was hoping there was a link somewhere that I had missed.

Comment: No, the page clearly says that a special driver is not needed, just the standard CUDA driver that comes with the Nvidia drivers.