# Login to docker nvcr.io failes if log in statement is written in one line in cmd prompt (Linux)?

Tags: docker, authentication, cmd

I am currently trying to login to the docker registry from nvidia and I want to accomplish this in one line in the cmd.
Therefore I followed the instructions from [this nvidia page](https://docs.nvidia.com/dgx/ngc-registry-for-dgx-user-guide/index.html#ngc-registry-overview).

I was able to successfully log in on my device if I do it the following way:

```
docker login nvcr.io
Username: $oauthtoken
Password: <my-generated-API-key>
```

However I want to login to nvcr.io in my ci/cd pipeline in gitlab. Therefore I need this command to work in one line. Before I put it in my .gitlab-ci.yml I tried it on my device locally and it always leads to an error. I already found a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71628120/docker-login-nvcr-io-v2-404) but there the error was a typo and the statement was not written in one line.

So I tried:

```
docker login nvcr.io -u "$oauthtoken" -p <my-generated-API-token>
```

Therefore the command line wants me to enter again the username. However I already provided the username.

```
docker login nvcr.io -u $oauthtoken -p <my-generated-API-token>
```

This lead to the error:

```
"docker login" requires at most 1 argument.
See 'docker login --help'.

Usage:  docker login [OPTIONS] [SERVER]
```

I also tried:

```
echo <my-generated-API-token> | docker login nvcr.io -u "$oauthtoken"
```

this lead to:

```
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
```

So I am confused, how can I write this docker login statement in one line?

Comment: The behavior you're describing suggests the `$oauthtoken` variable isn't set.  Can you double-check that?

Comment: thanks I already found my mistake. I must write -u '$oauthtoken' instead of "$oauthtoken".